# How are CUDA arrays stored in GPU memory? Are they physically linear or not?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, gpu

According to the CUDA TOOLKIT DOCUMENTATION:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/

Device memory can be allocated either as linear memory or as CUDA arrays.

Does this mean that the CUDA arrays are not stored linearly in GPU memory?

In my experiment, I successfully dumped my data from GPU memory based on the cudamemcpy function. If my data is allocated by cudaMallocArray, does it mean that the data are not physically linear in GPU memory and need to be extracted by other API?

Comment: From the same document:

> CUDA arrays are opaque memory layouts optimized for texture fetching. They are described in Texture and Surface Memory.

> CUDA supports a subset of the texturing hardware that the GPU uses for graphics to access texture and surface memory. Reading data from texture or surface memory instead of global memory can have several performance benefits as described in Device Memory Accesses.

Comment: While I think its not disclosed, textures and such types of arrays are stored in a plane filling curve manner, such as the Hilbert or Z-curves.

Comment: So are CUDA arrays actually stored in the global memory? or somewhere else?           Or they are stored in global memory just like other data, but not in a linear form.

Comment: They are in "global" memory, meaning in the same physical resource that supports the logical global space, but the arrangement is unspecified.  You access them through the texture and surface mechanisms, which involve on-GPU-chip caches that access the underlying global memory allocation, according to some pattern which may change based on the exact texture definition and usage, and is unspecified.

Answer (score 4):

CUDA arrays are indeed stored in GPU device memory ("global" memory), and the bytes are not physically linear in memory. They are an opaque layout optimized for multichannel, multidimensional texture access and texture filtering. The format is undocumented, since it may change between GPU architectures.